# Accessing WallpaperManager in Android 8.1

Tags: android, wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I'm building a launcher and need to access the user's current background wallpaper but every time I launch the app I get the warning `W/WallpaperManager: No permission to access wallpaper, suppressing exception to avoid crashing legacy app.` in the logs.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();

ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.background);
imageView.setImageDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

This code returns the default stock background image rather than my actual background image. I've noticed this problem on a few other mainstream launchers (Evie, Launchair, etc) but it only seems to happen on my recently-updated Andorid 8.1 device.

Digging further into the actual Android Source code, I've found this:

```
if (context.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion <= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    Log.w(TAG, "No permission to access wallpaper, suppressing"
    + " exception to avoid crashing legacy app.");
} else {
    // Post-O apps really most sincerely need the permission.
    throw e;
}
```

But I can't seem to find a reference to the actual permission required.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your targetSDKVersion?

Comment: It's currently set to 26. I'll try setting it to 27

Comment: Yeah, try setting it to 27 and see what behavior is.

Comment: @lakshman.pasala Yep, as soon as I changed it, the app crashed because I needed to request the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Now, everything is working properly. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to go ahead and submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Api 27 (Android 8.1) devices, changing the `targetSdkVersion` to 27 and adding the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to the manifest fixes this.